# How to concatenate a character and two or more integers in Python and store them for further use in the program?

Tags: python

Here in my code I want to concatenate a character `D` and two integers `l` and `i` in a for loop.

```
l = 1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\Python_Programs\B1'):
p = root.split('\\')
NoOfDir = len(dirs)                 #Here NoOfDir is 2 for my directory structure
    for i in range(0, NoOfDir):
        Dli = p[-1] + os.sep + dirs[i]
        print(Dli)
```

**Desired output:**

```
B1\New1    # As D10
B1\New2    # As D11
```

Here `New1` and `New2` are the two child directories of root directory `B1`.
As well I want to use `D10` and `D11` for further use.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: so *l* is 1-based and *i* is 0-based?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: I am able to get the output as "B1\New1" and "B1\New2". But not able to save D10 and D11 for further use. Similar like sprintf() function in "C" language.

Answer (score 1):

Using a variable name that is dynamically generated is a bad idea. It's possible, using direct `__dict__` access, but there's no good way for your later code to know what the names used were. Instead, use a list or dictionary, which you can index (or iterate over). Here's a version of your code that uses a `D` dictionary, with keys that are `(l, i)` tuples:

```
l = 1 # I assume this gets incremented somewhere not shown
D = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\Python_Programs\B1'):
    p = os.path.split(root)
    for i, dir in enumerate(dirs):
        D[l, i] = os.path.join(p[-1], dir)
        print("D[{}, {}] = {}".format(l, i, D[l, i]))
```

This still has a logic issue though, as the dictionary keys are not unique between the iterations of the outer loop. Perhaps that's where `l` is supposed to be incremented? If so, here's an alternative version that gets `l` from `enumerate`:

```
import os.path

D = {}

for l, (root, dirs, files) in enumerate(os.walk(r'D:\Python_Programs\B1')):
    p = os.path.split(root)
    for i, dir in enumerate(dirs):
        D[l, i] = os.path.join(p[-1], dir)
        print("D[{}, {}] = {}".format(l, i, D[l, i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new variables you can use a dictionary and `Dli` could be a key.

```
Dli = 'D'+str(l)+str(i)
new_dic[Dli] = p[-1] + os.sep + dirs[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vars for save their variables for  further usage.

`vars()['new_global_var'] = 'bla'`

`print new_global_var`

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing from what the code looks like but instead of

```
 Dli = p[-1] + os.sep + dirs[i]
```

shouldn't you be using

```
os.path.join(p[-1], dirs[i])
```

You shouldn't have to worry about `os.sep` in the usual case when using file paths.

I think that you need to look at os.path as you've also doing a `string.split` when perhaps `os.path.split` is really what you want.

I think you're trying to solve a problem that `os.path` already solves.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

```
l = 1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\Python_Programs\B1'):
p = root.split('\\')
NoOfDir = len(dirs)                 #Here NoOfDir is 2 for my directory structure
    for i in range(0, NoOfDir):
        varName = 'D%d%d' % (l, i)
        globals()[varName] = p[-1] + os.sep + dirs[i]
        print(globals()[varName])
```

I hope it helps :)